# How do I access certain elements of a PHP multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array.

[image: Multidiminsional Array With "Pre" tags screenshot]

I have run a foreach loop and am trying to echo the client nicknames of the 2 users. The code I am running is as follows.

```
$client_r = $Ts3->clientList();

foreach ($client_r as $client)
    {
        echo $client['data']['client_nickname'];
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: assuming that your image is what's in `$client_r` only one iteration of of your for each will have the data from your data element so there won't be a `$client['data']`. if you want to get the separate client nicknames you need to do a foreach on `$client_r['data']` then access with `$client['client_nickname'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($client_r as $client)
{
    echo $client['data'][0]['client_nickname'];
    echo $client['data'][1]['client_nickname'];

    // As there are further arrays inside array, so you have to include the index also
}
```

Comment: assuming that the image in the link of the question is `$client_r` this wont work because in one iteration `$client` will be `$client_r['data']`

Answer (score 0):

If you start from the `data` then your access will be easy-

In data you have again array, so the `$client` now stores the sub array, now you can easily access your `client_nickname`.

```
$client_r = $Ts3->clientList();

foreach ($client_r['data'] as $client){
    echo $client['client_nickname'];
}
```

This may be solve your problem.